# PM4Py - getting trace subset based on start activity

Tags: python

Consider this event trace - `a -> b -> c -> d -> e`. I want to get the subset of event trace given the starting node.

So if the starting node is `b`, I'd like the code to return `b -> c -> d -> e`. But that's not how the `pm4py.filter_start_activities` function works. This just returns the trace if the trace starts with the given starting node. It doesn't return the subset.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the traces from the event log which start with a certain activity you can use following code:

```
from pm4py.algo.filtering.log.start_activities import start_activities_filter
log_start = start_activities_filter.get_start_activities(log)
filtered_log = start_activities_filter.apply(log, ["S1"])
```

If you want to delete the prefix of all existing traces (what comes before your "starting activity"), you'll have to write a custom function. If it's easier to not work with the EventLog objects you cna always convert into a pandas dataframe and back.